# SSD slow write speed on Ubuntu

Tags: ssd, performance, nvme

I installed Samsung nvme 960 ssd on my laptop a few days ago which has max write speed up to 1500MB/s. Performance improved greatly but writing speed max at 600MB/s when I test benchmark with Disk software.

First I thought reason of slow write speed might be driver issue with linux or my hardware. But could not shake it, so tested with Ubuntu 17.10 live and found the same result. Then just to be sure I tested benchmark on live Linux Mint 18.2 and found write speed maxed at 1550MB/s! I have attached screenshots of both tests.

- [max write speed 1550MB/s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zm9A8.jpg)
- [max write speed 600MB/s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyLCv.png)

I was hoping if anyone can help me fix this slow write speed on Ubuntu. My laptop is Asus N552VX (i5 6300HQ, 8GB ram, 4GB Nvidia 950 gfx, Ubuntu 17.10).

**Update** 20/2/18:

After some feedback from other users on facebook, I did live testing again using old Ubuntu and latest Mint. Here is the result:

- Ubuntu 16.04.0 (kernel 4.4) = write speed 1.3 GB/s and read 2.0 GB/s.
- Mint 18.3 (kernel 4.10) = write speed 510 MB/s and read 3.0 GB/s.

So it seems latest kernel or updated latest distro is not efficient with resource usage. Though I am not sure if the new kernel is the reason or some other updated software. Hopefully in future, there will be some fix or improvement.

Comment: Where did you download the benchmarking software from? I'd like to duplicate test on my 960.

Comment: Ubuntu has a app called DISKS, search it from app menu. And here is tutorial to do benchmarking https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/disk-benchmark.html

Note: The partition ubuntu is installed on can't be benchmarked. You will have to choose another partition of your 960 ssd. Make sure you choose "perform write-benchmark" to test write benchmarking.

Comment: Couldn't do the write test because it wouldn't let me select an unmounted partition, only the mounted one. I have 7 partitions so I'm unclear what was going on. I'll try again later but the read test was 2.9 GB/s.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that you can only benchmark a single partition not whole disk (not sure why but HDD okay with that). To benchmark single partition first select a partition and then select benchmark partition from setting icon menu after partition blocks. Check this link for screenshot https://imgur.com/a/YbrjJ

Comment: The screenshot was most helpful. My write speed is worse than yours about 450 MB/sec.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, linux mint does not have this problem. I wonder why ubuntu has this big margin.

Comment: I'm wondering why it is so low myself. I might have to install Linux Mint this coming long week-end and try it out. When I did the Windows benchmark after I got the laptop it was 3.4 GB/s read and 2 GB/s write.

Comment: You can test using live linux mint. And regarding your slow speed than mine, check this page for ssd optimization https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/ssd. Ubuntu might have auto triming feature, so I ignored auto timing. You can try triming manually using this command "sudo fstrim -v /" and then check benchmark again. Please be cautious and good luck.

Comment: `$ sudo fstrim -v /

/: 6.3 GiB (6743732224 bytes) trimmed
` Still about 450 MB/sec write speed though

Comment: Its latest kernel or some updated software issue, please check my update on question.

Comment: The same with debian 10 and 4.16 kernel with 970 evo (read: 3500MB/s, write 700MB/s). Did someone find a resolution ?

Comment: Same on ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.4

Comment: Same ubuntu 18.04 kernel 5.4 silicon power p34a80. On win10 speed is flying

Comment: Wonder if it ever going to be fixed. Such a waste of resource.