# How to disable disk cache of NVMe SSD

Tags: ssd, cache, nvme

I know `hdparm -W0 /dev/sata-ssd` can disable disk cache for SATA SSD, but this does not work on my NVMe SSD (i.e., Samsung 980 pro). Maybe some option of `nvme` can do it, but I failed to find it.

How can I make this?

Thanks.

Comment: Does [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1281886/how-to-view-and-enable-write-cache-in-pcie-nvme-samsung-ssd-950pro-in-ubuntu-lin) address your issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this via the `nvme` commands, but I'm curious to know why you would want to do this. Disabling the cache will save a bit of RAM if that's the goal, bit it will cut your throughput in half at the very least.

Either way, this is how you do it:

```
# nvme get-feature -f 6 /dev/nvme0n1 
get-feature:0x6 (Volatile Write Cache), Current value:0x000001
# nvme set-feature -f 6 -v 0 /dev/nvme0n1 
set-feature:06 (Volatile Write Cache), value:00000000
# nvme get-feature -f 6 /dev/nvme0n1 
get-feature:0x6 (Volatile Write Cache), Current value:00000000
```

If for some reason you elect to make this persistent across reboots, you will need to write a `udev` rule:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="nvme*", RUN+="nvme set-feature -f 6 -v 0 %N"
```

These commands work with my Samsung 970 Pro, so should work with your device as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Because I found that my Samsung 980 pro is slower than my Samsung 860 evo (i.e., `fsync()` latency). I suspect the disk cache may lead to this. So I want to disable them to make a comparision.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer instead of just saying "why would you want to know that, haha regards".

Comment: When I try this, I just get "feature not namespace specific". Any Idea why?

Comment: Disk caches could slow cluster storage down:
https://yourcmc.ru/wiki/Ceph_performance#Drive_cache_is_slowing_you_down

Comment: If you get the "feature not namespace specific" error, try using set-feature against "nvme0" instead of "nvme0n1" (adjusting of course for whatever the identifier of your disk is).